# How to in C++ substitute the dynamic polymorphism by the static one?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, static-polymorphism

Let's say I have following code exploiting the dynamic polymorphism in C++

GraphicalObject.h

```
class GraphicalObject
{
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};
```

Rectangle.h

```
#include "GraphicalObject.h"

class Rectangle : public GraphicalObject
{
    void draw();
};
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

void Rectangle::draw() {
    std::cout << "Drawing rectangle!" << std::endl;
}
```

Circle.h

```
#include "GraphicalObject.h"

class Circle : public GraphicalObject
{
    void draw();
};
```

Circle.cpp

```
#include "Circle.h"
#include <iostream>

void Circle::draw() {
    std::cout << "Drawing circle!" << std::endl;
}
```

main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Rectangle rectangle;
    Circle circle;

    GraphicalObject* picture[2];
    
    picture[0] = &rectangle;
    picture[1] = &circle;
    
    for(GraphicalObject* o : picture) {
        o->draw();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

My question is whether there is a possibility how to have the `picture` array
without dynamic polymorphism and instead of use only the static polymorphism and
avoid the virtual method? The reason why I would like to avoid the virtual method is that I would like to avoid the overhead related to the access into the vtable.

Comment: Not if you want to store them in the same array like that.

Comment: `std::tuple<Rectangle, Circle> pictures; std::apply([](const auto& shape){ (shape.draw(), ...); }, pictures)`?

Comment: Why do you want to replace it? What do you want to improve? Seems like you've got a classic dynamic polymorphism example there.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili thank you for your response. My intention is to avoid the overhead related to the vtable access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that objects pointed by `GraphicalObject* picture[2];` got static type `GraphicalObject` and static polymorphism uses static type.

But that doesn't mean static polymorphism isn't possible is similar situation. You would need a wrapper class which would know the actual type of stored object and would cast the pointer to it before calling the methods.

Comment: Pie thank you for your response. May I ask you for an outline of your idea?

Comment: @Steve really depends on what you actually want to achieve. In general case replacement of virtual calls would exactly to be an implementation of virtual calls in other form, as vtable pointer is just a pointer to array of pointer to members. Overhead of virtual call is just one pointer dereference. If you need just a generalized storage, which would contain instances of multiple types but each consumer would be using only one type, In that case static polymorphism allows to exclude overhead of _function_ call by inlining it, if its possible. you probably would be using `std::variant`.